# $location.url not changing the url, but reloading instead

Tags: angularjs

if the user isn't logged in then I set $window.location.url = '/login'.

This works on every page except one and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm looking for ideas.
The code is:

```
debugger;
$location.url('/login')
debugger;
```

The first debugger triggers, and the second one never triggers (as expected), but the page reloads on the same url /admin/projects/create. This doesn't occur with /admin/organizations/create or /admin

What could possibly get in the way of $location.url()? There should be nothing that could get in the way, there must be something I'm missing with how location works.

[btw ive tried .path, as well as window.location and window.url, they all produce the same thing. I'm out of ideas.]

Comment: Why not `$location.path('/login')`?

Comment: It didn't work either, but no specific reason.

Comment: Can you post your routes code ?